# Scaladoc-like improved javadoc format?

Tags: javadoc

Is there a way to generate Javadocs that are comparable in functionality to the [documentation of the Scala library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current) (done with scaladoc)? In comparison to the [JDK documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) done with Javadoc this is lightyears ahead in many respects:

- there is a search field to look for classes
- there are switches whether include the inherited classes / interfaces and whether to show only public members
- you can hide packages / focus on packages easily
- you can easily decollapse / collapse the actual member description from the list of all members
- the source is linked

and more. Is there a tool to improve [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html) at least a little in that direction?

Comment: The [javadoc-search-frame userscript](https://code.google.com/p/javadoc-search-frame/) is a small, but oh-so-good step in that direction. And it can be applied to *every* JavaDoc ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any Doclet that generates such high-quality documentation.

But a small step in the right direction is the [javadoc-search-frame userscript](https://code.google.com/p/javadoc-search-frame/). Once you install it in your browser, every JavaDoc you navigate to will have a simple, but functional search frame.

Including that into a proper JavaDoc build should not be too hard.